# Why was the explain query output giving me BasicCursor eventhough the collection had indexes on it?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named stocks , i created a compound index on it as shown below

```
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"type": 1, "isValid": 1,"rootsymbol":1,"price":1},{"unique" : false})
```

I have set profilinglevel ,  to find out all the slow queries .

One of the query was below took 38 millis , when  did explain on it , this was the below result

Sorry i have updated my question

```
db.stocks.find({ query: { symbol: "AAPLE", date: "2014-01-18", type: "O", isValid: true }, orderby: { price: "1" } }).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 705402,
        "nscannedObjects" : 705402,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 3456,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

**My question is why its showing a BasicCursor even though it had indexes on it ??**

Comment: Explain doesn't take the query...

Comment: @Sammaye I have updated my question . i have put up this inside the find .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the issue here is your use of the `find()` function. You are specifying a `query` parameter and inside it, placing your search criteria. I don't think that you need to actually put `query` in there. Simply insert your search criteria. Something like this:

```
db.stocks.find({ 
  symbol: "AAPLE", 
  date: "2014-01-18", 
  type: "O", 
  isValid: true 
}).sort( { "price": 1} ).explain();
```

Note also my changes to the sorting. You can read more about sorting a cursor [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort).

Comment: i was getting Tue Sep 10 11:55:17 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (shell):0

Comment: Ahh... hehe... I think it's your `orderby` syntax. Take a look at my updated answer...

Comment: Lix , that worked , now i got "BtreeCursor" but why the system.profile is actually pritinting queries as order by ??

Comment: @pre - not too sure about that one. I haven't had much experience with the profiler

Comment: The problem is the use of in query operators with functional operators, it is a bug

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem isn't actually described I will go on to describe it.

You are calling top level query operators with functional operators. So for example you call query operators here:

```
{ query: { symbol: "AAPLE", date: "2014-01-18", type: "O", isValid: true }, orderby: { price: "1" } }
```

In the form of `query` and `orderby` but then you call a functional operator:

`explain();`

This is a known bug with MongoDB that these two do not play well together and so produce the output you get.

Of course when the query comes in and is parsed by MongoDB it is recorded in the profile with query operators `query` and `orderby` and `maxscan` etc.

This is more of a problem when calling the command.

Reference: [MongoDB $query operator ignores index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608642/mongodb-query-operator-ignores-index) I couldn't find the actual JIRA for this but this is related.

Edit: I think this vaguely represents it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6767

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not the problem. In order for MongoDB to use a compound index (ie, an index that contains more than one field), the fields in your query/sort must be a *prefix* of the index fields. In this case, your index includes these fields: symbol, date, type, isValid, rootsymbol, and price. Your query/sort includes all fields **except** `rootsymbol`, so the index cannot be used. Possible solutions:

- Remove `rootsymbol` from the index, or
- Add `rootsymbol` to your query, or
- If you can't do either of the above, create another index without `rootsymbol`

[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes)

Regarding the syntax, there **is** in fact a query syntax in which an index cannot be used: the `$where` clause requires evaluating inline JavaScript, so indexes cannot be used. For example:

```
db.collection.find( { $where: "field1.value > field2.value" } )
```